# SQL lite in Azure CAST(date AS datetime)

Tags: sqlite, azure

I want to fix my date column from this:  2009-01-09T00:00:00

To this: 2009-01-09

Im running it on SQL lite in Azure ML

I tried this code:

```
select CAST(date AS datetime) 

from t1;
```

But all it returns is 2009

I also tried this code:

```
select CAST(date AS date) 

from t1;
```

But with the same result : 2009 only

I would prefer to use CAST and not CONVERT (or similar)

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite3 does not have a DATETIME type, so it is interpreted as NUMERIC (please see https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html for an explanation), using CAST on your string will result as you have seen in its being scanned as an integer.  To get what you want, use the `substr(X,Y,Z)` function (see https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr ).